# Using UINavigationItem on UITabBarController

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have a project with a `UITabBarController` and a couple of views.  Sort of like this:

[image]

In this project, the tab bar controller is called by tapping the Tab button on the `UIViewController`.  I would like to get rid of the back button with "Title", and replace it with an "X" icon.  When tapped, the "X" icon would dismiss the `UITabBarController` and return to the caller.  I do this all of the time on `UINavigationController` using a `UINavigationItem`, but that does not appear to work in this situation.  I drag the `UINavigationItem` to the view and it allows it, but it does not show up on the view and any `UIBarButtonItem` that I drag and drop on it do not appear.

Is there a way to actually do this?  I'd even be ok with leaving the existing back button as it is and just getting rid of "Title"

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out right after posting the question.  Just a bit more research is all it took.

To fix this, add the following to the `UITabBarController` code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let buttonImage = UIImage(named: "back")

    let leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(dismissTabBar))
    leftButton.tintColor = UIColor.black

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
}

@IBAction func dismissTabBar() {
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

This gives me a black back button with my image.  When I tap it, it brings me back to the calling 'UIViewController.